# "Uploadcare" Issue using PHP

Tags: php, uploadcare

I'm facing a very peculiar issue when attempting to grab the UUID from an image upload using upload care's PHP Library. The images are getting successfully uploaded back into my Uploadcare storage with their correlating UUID's, however in my php script when i attempt to grab the UUID from the file input, the request object is coming back an empty string.

**Here are the imported Uploadcare script tags and input tag, respectively:** *as instructed in the [PHP Library Repo](https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-php#readme?utm_source=uploadcare.com&utm_medium=uploadcare&utm_campaign=quick_start_php)

```
<script>UPLOADCARE_PUBLIC_KEY = "2a92ab6d0aaae8efe942";</script>
<script src="https://ucarecdn.com/widget/2.9.0/uploadcare/uploadcare.full.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>


<input type="hidden" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="file_id" data-upload-url-base="">
```

Now I have noticed in the inspector console, during the uploading of the image, AND ONLY DURING THIS OCCURRENCE, I get the following

> Failed to load resource. Could not connect to the server http://localhost:0/

error:

[image]

I've restarted my Server (using MAMP btw) numerous times. All my code seems to be correct as I noted earlier, the images are successfully being uploaded back into my Uploadcare storage...

**ANY SUGGESTIONS?**

---

**UPDATE**

Here is my code as constructed at the moment. I am using the Slim Framework in accordance with Twig as my templating engine:

```
use Uploadcare\Api;

$app->container->singleton('uploadcare', function() {

  return new Api('2a92ab6d0aaae8efe942', 'SECRET KEY');

});
```

In my view I have the following twig syntax which produces the needed Uploadcare scripts and input tag:

```
<head>
   {{ app.uploadCare.widget.getScriptTag | raw }}
    <script>
      UPLOADCARE_LIVE = false;
      UPLOADCARE_DO_NOT_STORE = true;
      UPLOADCARE_TABS = 'file';
      UPLOADCARE_IMAGES_ONLY = true;
      UPLOADCARE_CROP = 'free';
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form enctype='multipart/form-data' method="post">
       {{ app.uploadCare.widget.getInputTag('file_id') | raw }}
    </form>
</body>
```

now all I'm doing is a `var_dump` on my `request` object when the form is submitted, which shows the `file_id` parameter coming back with an empty string rather than the UUID/new url of the uploaded image:

```
$request = $app->request;
var_dump($request->post('file_id'));
```

which echoes:

```
string(0) ""
```

**UPDATE 2**

below is a shot of the network activity during the selection of a file via uploadcare's api file input. As you can see, one of the GET request fail and I'm guessing that is the request that is causing the malfunction:

[image]

Comment: can you add a gist of rendered HTML?

Comment: It renders the exact HTML I placed in the initial question post. The `getScriptTag` function renders the necessary scripts needed and the `getInputTag()` function renders the file input @mojo

Comment: please check second update @mojo

Comment: there's some kind of template, not HTML, please dont expect people on SO to know your particular template language. And it may introduce it's own problems too.

Comment: particular network activity screenshot shows nothing(
are files uploaded successfully before form is being submitted? if so, is input field populated properly or not (check via dom inspector)?

Comment: even when i substitute the tempting syntax with the native HTML, the same issue still arises. Yes the files are being successfully uploaded before form submission but no value is being returned into the `file_id` input. @mojo

Comment: my input field is rendered as such `<input type="hidden" role="uploadcare-uploader" name="file_id" data-upload-url-base="">` @mojo

Comment: @JaredGarcia what version of Slim are you using?

Comment: versio 2 @OmarKhazamov

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `data-upload-url-base=""`, it instructs the widget to use "empty" upload servers instead of `upload.uploadcare.com`

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. Im at a standstill. I know uploadcare automatically uploads the selected file up to my account backend via AJAX, because when I inspect the network activity, on the selection of a file, the AJAX request is successfully fired and JSON objects containing the newly uploaded image as well as UUID are given back in a response. However, its just not being recognized in my $_POST global.